# Problema con llaves foráneas MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, table

//Tengo 3 tablas//

CREATE TABLE departamento(

```
id_departamento int NOT null PRIMARY KEY,

nombre varchar(45)

)
```

CREATE TABLE trabajadores(

```
cod_trabajar int NOT null,

ci_trab int NOT null,

nss int(5),

nombre varchar(45),

apellido varchar(45),

telefono int(10),

direccion varchar(10),

id_departamento int NOT null,

CONSTRAINT fk_id_departamento FOREIGN KEY (id_departamento) REFERENCES departamento (id_departamento)

)
```

CREATE TABLE categoria(

```
id_categoria int NOT null PRIMARY KEY,

nombre varchar(45)

)
```

//El problema está al crear la 4ta. tabla llamada "contratos"//

CREATE TABLE contratos(

```
n_contrato int NOT null,

fecha_inicial date,

fecha_final date,

id_categoria int NOT null,

cod_trabajar int NOT null,

CONSTRAINT fk_id_categoria FOREIGN KEY (id_categoria) REFERENCES categoria (id_categoria),

CONSTRAINT fk_cod_trabajar FOREIGN KEY (cod_trabajar) REFERENCES trabajadores (cod_trabajar)
```

)

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `prueba1`.`contratos` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Detalles…)

//¿Cuál sería la solución a esto? :(//

Comment: segun lo que veo el error esta en la tabla trabajadores, primero define cod_trabajadores como llave primaria, es importante definir tus llaves primarias en las tablas

Comment: @CRIS19N Muchas gracias, ese era el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dejo en script de la bd.

mi recomendacion principal, es que define un campo primario en cada tabla.

generalmente yo uso un administrador de MySQL,(hediSQL)
pero si lo esta haciendo por consola, debes usar el comando `PRIMARY KEY  cod_tabla` para definir tu llave primaria.

tambien recuerda que tanto la llave foranea como el campo al que hace referencia deben compartir la misma estructura de datos.

```
-- Volcando estructura de base de datos para prueba
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `prueba` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci */;
USE `prueba`;

-- Volcando estructura para tabla prueba.categoria
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categoria` (
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_categoria`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;


-- Volcando estructura para tabla prueba.contratos
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contratos` (
  `n_contrato` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_inicial` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_final` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_categoria` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cod_trabajar` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `id_categoria` (`id_categoria`),
  KEY `cod_trabajar` (`cod_trabajar`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_contratos_categoria` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`id_categoria`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_contratos_trabajadores` FOREIGN KEY (`cod_trabajar`) REFERENCES `trabajadores` (`cod_trabajar`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

-- Volcando estructura para tabla prueba.departamento
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `departamento` (
  `id_departamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_departamento`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
 
-- Volcando estructura para tabla prueba.trabajadores
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trabajadores` (
  `cod_trabajar` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ci_trab` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nss` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefono` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_departamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cod_trabajar`),
  KEY `fk_id_departamento` (`id_departamento`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_departamento` FOREIGN KEY (`id_departamento`) REFERENCES `departamento` (`id_departamento`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```